# Pods - ignore specific package

Tags: xcode, react-native, cocoapods, react-native-ios

I'm using a react-native package, in which is required to manual link with Xcode before it can successfully run.

If I install new packages with npm, and they require me to do a pod install, I get the manual linked package added to podfile again, and I don't want that.

Is there a way to make the podfile not install a specific package?

Comment: Would it make sense to comment this pod out in Podfile?

Comment: No, pod install finds pod needed modules and adds them.